# Python Modulenotfounderror (New to programming)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, new-operator

When I install Pyautogui through the Python -m pip install pyautogui it goes through and download. But when I run my code which contains `import Pyautogui` I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/kalle/.PyCharmCE2018.3/config/scratches/ytbot.py", line 9, in <module>
    import pyautogui
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyautogui'
```

Comment: Have you got multiple versions of Python installed on your machine?

Comment: This `Python -m pip install...` is Python 2.x. Use `Python -m pip3 install...` as you have taged `[python-3.x]`

Comment: @stovfl Tried this but it said no module named pip3 in windows powershell

Comment: @KalleL: Read [how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows)